# Cannot Browse Non-Text Messages From Hawtio

Tags: jboss, spring-jms, hawtio, jboss-amq

Currently i'm working in implementing ActiveMQ message broker in my application. We are using RedHat JBoss Hawtio management console to browse the message. We are not able to read the ObjectMessage in the management console. Normal text messages are showing up fine. I saw similar problem already reported as a bug in Jboss issue tracker but i'm not seeing any solution. Would like to check with our community experts to see if anyone have some solution/workaround to this problem. This is the error message i'm seeing in management console.

```
Unsupported message body type which cannot be displayed by hawtio
```

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-4074

Answer (score 1):

As concluded in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-4074 currently it's not possible to render `ObjectMessage` in hawtio. ActiveMQ needs to implement https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4817 to realise the feature.

According to Claus in ENTESB-4074:

> I assume an ObjectMessage is a java serialized object, even if you marshal that to bytes then the data is not readable by humans.

Comment: Thank you Tad for the udpate, let me explore @JsonMBean.